What's the proper to phrase a question pertaining to good practices so that it doesn't get closed?
I asked a question about good practices: Are there good practices or even conventions to store LLM prompts I use while coding?
It got closed as opinion-based. I looked at other questions tagged programming-practices but I couldn't spot any major differences that made them escape opinion-based closures. What's the proper to phrase a question pertaining to good practices so that it doesn't get closed?

I voted to reopen - there were already two votes to reopen. I don't see how it's fundamentally different than other good practice questions.
However, I wouldn't expect an answer to this question. LLMs and generative AI are so new, and the landscape is changing so quickly that there aren't general best practices. Given the breadth of tooling, there may also not be anything generalized yet. With these open and unanswered questions about this class of tool, this is likely to be unanswerable.

Thanks, "there aren't general best practices" sounds like a valid answer.

I was one of the close voters, and I would still vote to close it again, if I wasn't overruled. For me, the whole question reads very like "how do you take electronic notes during coding". LLM prompts are just text snippets, and if one wants to keep them, they could use

a text editor

a spreadsheet

a word processor

a Wiki

there famous note-taking app

pieces of paper


In a comment under the question, Greg Burkhardt wrote "... There are a zillion ways to do this with no clear way that is better than the others.". This is exactly how I see this. I have no idea why Greg voted for reopening later, I would have not.
Additionally, I think the "AI" part is just a red herring - LLMs prompts are IMHO not different from other kind of notes one may want to keep.
So I don't think this question can be made less opinionated by a slight rephrasing, it seems to be fundamentally opinion based.
There are some other issues I see with the question:

it uses a "programming-practices" tag, which was discussed years ago if it should be nuked,

it is technically a list-of-things question, which is never a good fit for this site's Q&A format.


But even by solving these issues, I don't think there is a chance to make this question less opinionated.
